# changin the font color for a div that is inside a span?

Tags: css

i have a jquery menu and this is the css style

```
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link,
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr,
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
    margin-left:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
    font-family:"arial black";
```

the sdt link is the menu box but when hover the box drops down two divs
the sdt descrb is a picture that enlarges
but the sdt box a is the last box that i want to style

because its black any text in there doesnt display also these arial black doesnt affect it either

how can i style only this box because when i try this it doesnt work

```
 ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
font-family:"arial black";
color: yellow; 
}
```

Comment: I can has http://jsfiddle.net/?  The CSS you've provided isn't looking for a div within a span.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a block level element inside of an in-line element.

Comment: While this is true, it is not an answer to the question.